# I suggested an edit for updating formatting which was accepted but the author just rolled back the change to the previous unformatted state

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

I suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49672129/revisions) edit for updating formatting which was accepted by the community but the author just rolled back the change to the previous unformatted state.  It seems there is no direct recourse of action that couldn't just be rolled back again arbitrarily. The style tag added code formatting readability and was appropriate to the code language.  What is the course of action in this case?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49672129/revisions

Comment: As the owner of the post, they're free to disagree with an edit, just as someone else is free to go in and redo it.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange! As this question is only about a specific site in the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Each site has a *per-site meta* where you can ask questions about that site, which can be accessed through the site switcher on the top right corner. Questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site.

Comment: The post owner always has the final say. Why don't you leave a comment and ask if that jsx pretifier isn't better for those code blocks. Are you sure that `lang-jsx` is actually a thing? I don't see it mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100). If it can't find a pretifier it will fallback to the `lang-default` which does a lot of things ok-ish.

Comment: Also note that occasionally, due to the UI, users may accidentally override edits that they didn't intend to override.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic just because it's prompted by an SO question.  If the question asked "what's wrong with that edit" it would belong on SO meta, but it's asking how to proceed after the edit was rejected, and that's a question that's applicable across the network.

Comment: Did you change the formatting in which the text was presented—or did you *add* a line of code (the language tag). It's one thing to change a quotation to use a block quote, or change regular text to preformatted text, but unless you're fixing a typo, modifying the text (and especially code) isn't really appropriate. You can add a comment to say that perhaps a piece of code should be added—but you shouldn't edit the post to impose it on somebody else.

Comment: It was only a language tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best bet in a case like this is to ask the author.  It might have been an accident; maybe the author saw what appears to be a comment-only edit (if looking at the Markdown source) and thought it was noise.  Assume that you both want the same thing -- a clear question -- and proceed from there.  When I'm in your situation I usually leave a comment explaining why I made the edit and asking if the author meant to roll it back; if the person has enough rep I might suggest we retire to chat (depending on what the comment pile already looks like).